# Series expansion using Cauchy formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

In order to calculate the series expansion of $$f(z)=\frac{z+1}{(1-z)^2(z+2)}$$ around $z_0=0$, I am supposed to use a circle with radius $R$ in Cauchy's formula and to then take the limit $R\to\infty$.

My attempt: We know $f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}} dz$.
Plugging in yields $f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=R} \frac{z+1}{(1-z)^2(z+2)z^{n+1}} dz$, but I do not know how to proceed further. Does this not go to $0$ for $R\to\infty$? This would not agree with the coefficients I should be getting for the expansion.

Comment: This gives$$f^{(n)}(0)=n!\left[\lim_{z=-2}\frac{z+1}{(1-z)^2z^{n+1}}+\lim_{z=1}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{z+1}{(z+2)z^{n+1}}\right]+\lim_{z=0}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\frac{z+1}{(1-z)^2(z+2)}.$$Are you sure that's $0$?

Comment: Could you please explain how you got to that expression from the curve integral?

Comment: With [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher-order_poles).

Comment: Thank you. Another question: how would I go about calculating $\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\frac{z+1}{(1-z)^2(z+2)}$?

Comment: You could use partial fractions, but they provide an easy way to solve the original problem without the residue theorem.